# ColdFusion - Connect to LDAP Server

Tags: coldfusion, ldap, coldfusion-2016

I am using `cfldap` (ColdFusion 2016) to connect to an LDAP server but the server starts with `LDAPS://`. ColdFusion throws an error that it is an invalid name. When I try to connect without `LDAPS`,  it throws "An error has occured while executing the query. Below is the full tag I am using.

```
<cftry>
     <cfldap server="#servername#" 
             username="#username#"
             password="#password#"
             port="636" action="query"
             name="qryName"
             start="#start#"
             attributes="#attributes#"
             filter="#filter#"
             scope="SUBTREE"
             secure="cfssl_basic">

    <cfcatch type="any">
          <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
    </cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: The error message usually continues after `An error has occured...` What does it exactly read?

Comment: Thats all the message is. An error has occured while executing the query. :servername:636. I am not sure how to get a better error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to import the ldap server's certificate or if it is Active Directory the domain's CA certificate into the java keystore.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html

Also, here is an example os authenticating via Active Directory.

```
cfldap(
    server = "ServerName",
    port = 636,
    action = "QUERY",
    name = "qLDAPLookup",
    secure = "CFSSL_BASIC",
    username = "MYDOMAIN\#arguments.username#",
    password = arguments.password,
    start = "dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=MYTLD",
    attributes = "cn,userPrincipalName,title,mail",
    timeout = "10",
    filter = "(sAMAccountName=#arguments.username#)"
);

if (qLDAPLookup.recordCount) {
    userAuthenticated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a double quote after #start#. Not sure if that is in your actual code though.